# SQL delete selected with Javastcript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have made an list out of an sql database, this is coded in php. but i am now supposed to delete the selected item s from that list with the push of a button.

Can i do this in PHP or must i do this in Javascript, ans also how
Here is what i have until now:

```
<?php      
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","boodschappen");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM boodshappenlijst");

    echo "<ul class='list-group'>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo  "<li class='list-group-item'>";
    echo    "<span class='badge'>" . $row['Aantal'] . "</span>";
    echo    $row['Wat'];
    echo  "</li>";
    } 
  echo "</ul>";

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
    <script>
    $( "li" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use php, but you can combine it with Ajax. Or if you don't want to use javascript, just write it as form that does the action when submitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$( "li" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
  $( this ).hide();
});
</script>
```

This will delete item from the list. Unless of course you want to delete it also from the database - then look at answer Rikudou_Sennin gave you.

Comment: i understand what you mean, but i must also be able to unhighlight the part